# Can't call a JS function from a jsp file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to invoke **getInitialDropDown()** (a JS function) from **transactiondetails.jsp**. 
So what I have done is,

I include the **transaction.js**  at the end of the **transactiondetails.jsp** file.

```
<script src="<%=localrequestedURL%>resources/appjs/transaction.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then I invoke the  **getInitialDropDown()** method

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        getInitialDropDown();
    });
</script>
```

But it is not working. The function **getInitialDropDown()** is not getting called.

Here is my **transaction.js** file

```
function getInitialDropDown() {
    alert("called");
}
```

Comment: what error does your browser report? what does `localrequestedURL` output? does it have a trailing `/`? Maybe add `/` to your path before `resources`

Comment: What is localrequestedURL ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Comment: have you include jQuery library?